# Select all <p> after <h3> tag

Tags: html, css

This question might sound strange since an easy way to handle it is just to add a specific class or id to those

. But my html is rendered by some other tools so that I cannot manage those specific `<p>` myself, but I just want to padding the `<p>` after `<h3>` here. Those `<p>` are all children of a `<section>`, the code

```
<h3>ipsum</h3>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>foo</p>
```

I tried to solve this problem with h3 + p selector, but it can only do change to the first `<p>`. I want to select all the p after h3.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors

Comment: `+` has a companion, `~` … https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) `~` (instead of the *adjacent* sibling selector `+`):

```css
h3 ~ p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h3>ipsum</h3>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>foo</p>
```

Comment: I thought sibling are used under the case where they are all children to `<h3>`, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

> **+** : The + combinator selects adjacent siblings. This means that the second element directly follows the first, and both share the same parent.
>
> **~** : The ~ combinator selects siblings. This means that the second element follows the first (though not necessarily immediately), and both share the same parent.

So, use `~` instead of `+`

```
h3 ~ p {your code...}
```

```css
h3 ~ p { background-color:yellow }
```

```html
<h3>ipsum</h3>
<p>lorem</p>
<p>foo</p>
```